# ArcGIS 10 using ArcPy to save feature class table as a geodatabase table (i.e. without geometry)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, attribute-table

I have a point feature class where I need to - in arcpy - save the feature attribute table i.e. without the geometry. I need arcpy to do the same as Opening Attribute Table then Export the table, but not with cursors as this is a very large attribute table (very many points).

Comment: Table select http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000007000000 will do that. Supply the input table as your feature class and your output as attribute table... this tool uses the location and extension to decide what output format, if give the output file name as .dbf it will be in DBASE IV format, .TXT or .CSV it will export a text/CSV table and if you specify a location inside a database it will export as geodatabase table.

Comment: If you really are using ArcGIS 10.0, remember that this was an *early* release of Python support. Desktop has matured over the past six major builds, with more recent Python and much better Python integration. Given that 10.0 is in Retired support status, there aren't many here still using it,  so answers that work fine on modern releases might not work for you. You asked for other than a cursor solution, but modern Data Access cursors are sufficiently performant that they are now a viable option with a 40m row table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a couple of options for what you are after, all available via ArcPy.  In most cases, however, you'll probably want/need to precede the function by turning the table from something on disk to something analogous to adding it to ArcMap... a table view.  Use the "[Make Table View](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-table-view.htm)" tool/function to do this, then call your favorite conversion tool to actually write to disk.

They are all pretty much the same, and could likely be used interchangeably with those noted by @Fezter and @Michael Miles-Stimson.

1. [Table to Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-table.htm).  This has a few more options, but is generally harder to work with.
2. [Copy Rows](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-rows.htm).  I personally like this one because the inputs to
   the tool are more straightforward, and fits your simple input-output needs.

Comment: Thanks that solved it: preceding the write with the Make Table View

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done using the conversion tools.  **[Table to Excel](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000054000000)**. However, this isn't available until, I think 10.2.  From your tags, it looks like you're using 10.0, so as Michael Miles-Stimson commented, you can use the **[Table Select](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000007000000)** tool.